# Replace desktop tag with desktop-save-mode?

Tags: discussion, tags

I just took a look through the [desktop](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/desktop) tag, and almost all of the questions relate to `desktop-save-mode`. However, the word “desktop” is pretty general, and there were a handful of questions that used the [desktop](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/desktop) tag to indicate some relationship to their OS desktop. This isn't generally very useful.

I wonder if it might be more informative to use the tag name `desktop-save-mode` in place of `desktop`, to make it clearer what the tag refers to? `desktop-save-mode` hasn't been used yet, so I can't suggest one as a synonym for the other.

As I said, most uses of the [desktop](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/desktop) tag relate to saving and restoring sessions, so there's no urgent problem here. Just a suggestion!

Note that moderators can rename tags, so if we decide to rename the tag, please do not edit the questions that are about `desktop-save-mode`, only the ones that aren't.

Comment: What about the questions that refer to the desktop rather than `desktop-save-mode`? Should they get a new tag that isn't ambiguous?

Comment: Maybe. These used the `desktop` tag to indicate an issue directly tied to their particular OS desktop or OS desktop settings https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/30152/can-we-pick-our-emacs-proxy-settings-from-the-broader-settings-set-by-our-deskto https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/48788/emacs-stops-displaying-typing-until-focus-moved-out-of-and-then-back-into-editor

Comment: @DoMiNeLa10 If we had a good tag wiki maybe we'd be able to come up with a clear tag to use? I think my wiki for `desktop` (i.e., desktop-save-mode) is pretty clear, but I'm not sure how to describe a tag for questions like those two